# Does my solution work by accident?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

The task description is as follows (sorry for my poor translation - it's the best I could think of):

> There are three numbers that sum up to 105. They are subsequent items
>   in a growing geometric sequence (a, b, c). The first of those numbers
>   is the first number, the second number is the sixth number and the
>   third number is the twenty-sixth number in some arithmetic sequence.
>   What are those numbers?

Now, my solution is as follows:

Those three numbers expressed in terms of the second sequence are $(a, a + 5r, a + 25r)$ where r is the difference of the arithmetic sequence.
If so, then this is true (**am I right?**):

$$
a + a + 5r + a + 25r = 105\\
a = 35 - 10r
$$

Therefore the first sequence can be expressed as follows (**again: am I right?**): $(35 - 10r, 35 - 5r, 35 + 15r)$ .
And here comes the most important question in this post: am I allowed to divide each of those items in the final sequence by a number so that my next calculations will deal with lower numbers? I'm asking because I did that and in the end I got the right values for a, b and c, although I'm not sure if I didn't do something wrong (prob. I did). So, my next calculations were:

$$
(35 - 10r, 35 - 5r, 35 + 15r) / :5 \\ 
(7 - 2r, 7 - r, 7 + 3r)
$$

From the formula for a second item of a geometric sequence ($y^2 = x * z$ where y is the second item in the sequence, x is the first one and z the last one):

$$
(7 - r)^2 = (7 - 2r)(7 + 3r)\\
49 - 14r + r^2 = 49 + 21r - 14r - 6r^2\\
7r^2 = 21r\\
r = 3
$$

Now if I put $r$ into $(35 - 10r, 35 - 5r, 35 + 15r)$, the three numbers come out as 
$$
a = 5\\
b = 20\\
c = 80
$$

Why does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks correct.  The reason it works to divide through is that the equation you write for requiring that $a,b,c$ are a geometric sequence only depend on the relative proportions of $a,b,c$.  The equation you get is $b/a = c/b$ (equivalent to $b^2 = ac$), and you just reduced these fractions.